# two versions of python installed at two places

Tags: python, python-3.x

I had uninstalled python 3.8 from my system and installed 3.7.x
But after running the command `where python` and `where python3` in the cmd I get two different locations.
I was facing issues regarding having two versions of python. So I would like to know how i can completely remove python3 located files.

Comment: I would use the following from the terminal: sudo rm -rf Python

Comment: You might have a 2.x installation as well, that your system depends on and should not be removed.

Comment: It depends on your operating system. A other wrote: do no remove or update externally system python. Often `conda` is good tools to have parallel python version.

Answer (score 0):

To delete a specific python version, you can use `which python` and remove the python folder using `sudo rm -rf <path returned from the above command>`. You might also have to modify the PATH env variable to the location which contains the python executables of the version you want.

Or you can install Anaconda [https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual] which helps to manage multiple versions of python for you.

Comment: OP mentioned using `where`. That suggests they are using Windows and these commands wouldn't work. Additionally, a lot of linux systems depend upon the python that `which python` would return.